# Match multiple words in a list

Tags: python, list, parsing

I am working on parsing strings that contain ingredients.

I break the strings into lists of words
For example:

```
list1 = ['favorite','olive','oil']
list2 = ['favorite','oil']
```

And I have a list of ingredients that I need to match with the words in the list. For example,

```
ingredients = ['sesame oil', 'olive oil', 'olive juice', 'oil']
```

I need a function that returns `olive oil` in the first scenario and `oil` in the second.

Any tips and recommendations are highly appreciated.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 1):

This would provide a list of the overlap between one of the lists and the ingredients. This might be useful in case more than one item in the list is in the set of ingredients.

```
def ingredient_checker(checklist):
    ingredients = ['sesame oil', 'olive oil', 'olive juice', 'oil']
    return [item for item in set(checklist).intersection(ingredients)]

>>> list3 = ['favorite','olive','oil', 'olive juice']
>>> ingredient_checker(list3)
['oil', 'olive juice']
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult what you mean by: "in the first scenario" and "second scenario".  This is rather ambiguous.

Given that, I will go with suggesting.  What would probably be best as a data structure is to have your list as favorites in order and then return a list of matched ingredients in order.  If I had to write this I would probably write something more like this:

```
favorites = [['olive', 'oil'], ['oil']]
ingredients = ['sesame oil', 'olive oil', 'olive juice', 'oil']

def get_favorite_ingredients(favorite_list=[], ingred=[]):
    matched = []
    for fav in favorite_list:
        if ' '.join(fav) in ingred:
            matched.append(' '.join(fav))
    return matched

# this returns: ['olive oil', 'oil']
print get_favorite_ingredients(favorites, ingredients)
```

That way it's clear in order of the array, where the first position is the first found favorite of most importance, second position is the second found favorite of most importance etc...  It wouldn't matter how many favorites and how many ingredients, as long as the favorite list is in the order you wish that same order is always given back.  Hope this helps!